# WsOpenServiceHost returns WS_E_OTHER

Tags: web-services, visual-c++

I'm tryind to run [HttpCalculatorServiceExample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd323329(v=vs.85).aspx#wsw.calculatorservice.wsdl) located in MSDN. Function  `WsOpenServiceHost` returns error code `0x803d0021`. This error means

```
 MessageId: WS_E_OTHER
 Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework.
```

Printed  error:

```
Unable to add URL to HTTP URL group.
Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

How to solve this problem?

```
int __cdecl wmain(int argc, __in_ecount(argc) wchar_t **argv)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argv);

    HRESULT hr = NOERROR;
    WS_SERVICE_HOST* host = NULL;
    WS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT serviceEndpoint = {};
    const WS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT* serviceEndpoints[1];
    serviceEndpoints[0] = &serviceEndpoint;

    WS_ERROR* error = NULL;

    WS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_PROPERTY serviceEndpointProperties[1];
    WS_SERVICE_PROPERTY_CLOSE_CALLBACK closeCallbackProperty = {CloseChannelCallback};
    serviceEndpointProperties[0].id = WS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT_PROPERTY_CLOSE_CHANNEL_CALLBACK;
    serviceEndpointProperties[0].value = &closeCallbackProperty;
    serviceEndpointProperties[0].valueSize = sizeof(closeCallbackProperty);


    // Initialize service endpoint
    serviceEndpoint.address.url.chars = L"http://+:80/example"; // address given as uri
    serviceEndpoint.address.url.length = (ULONG)wcslen(serviceEndpoint.address.url.chars);
    serviceEndpoint.channelBinding = WS_HTTP_CHANNEL_BINDING; // channel binding for the endpoint
    serviceEndpoint.channelType = WS_CHANNEL_TYPE_REPLY; // the channel type
    serviceEndpoint.contract = &calculatorContract;  // the contract
    serviceEndpoint.properties = serviceEndpointProperties;
    serviceEndpoint.propertyCount = WsCountOf(serviceEndpointProperties);

    // Create an error object for storing rich error information
    hr = WsCreateError(
        NULL, 
        0, 
        &error);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Exit;
    }
    // Create Event object for closing the server
    closeServer = CreateEvent(
        NULL, 
        TRUE, 
        FALSE, 
        NULL);
    if (closeServer == NULL)
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        goto Exit;
    }   
    // Creating a service host
    hr = WsCreateServiceHost(
        serviceEndpoints, 
        1, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        &host, 
        error);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Exit;
    }
    // WsOpenServiceHost to start the listeners in the service host 
    hr = WsOpenServiceHost(
        host, 
        NULL, 
        error);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {

        goto Exit;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(closeServer, INFINITE);
    // Close the service host
    hr = WsCloseServiceHost(host, NULL, error);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Exit;
    }

Exit:
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Print out the error
        PrintError(hr, error);
    }
    fflush(
        stdout);
    if (host != NULL)
    {
        WsFreeServiceHost(host);
    }


    if (error != NULL)
    {
        WsFreeError(error);
    }
    if (closeServer != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(closeServer);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    return SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework", while tried to debug remote target (C++ project). 
I've tried all possible solutions, which I've found over internet: turn-off/uninstall  antivirus(I use MS Essentials), turnoff firewall, reinstall VS etc. 
But it didn't help.

So, I've deleted all programms (not windows updates) which I've installed last month, reboot computer, and the bug went away.

Uninstalled software:

- Foxit PhantomPDF Standard. Версия: 7.0.5.1021.
- widecap
- CCleaner
- Uninstall Tool
- just in case, I've also uninstalled Microsoft Security Essentials and after the bug went away I've installed it again and had no problems.

Hope, this helps